# Django REST Framework: TestCase is not returning correct queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest, django-testing

I have created an API, using `DRF`, for products in an inventory that can be accessed by the following endpoint `url(r'products/$', views.InventoryList.as_view(), name='product-list')`.

When issuing a `GET` request via postman, I get the correct queryset back, which is a total of `11` products:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Biscuits",
        "description": "Papadopoulou Biscuits",
        "price": "2.52",
        "comments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "title": "First comments for this",
                "comments": "Very tasty",
                "rating": 8,
                "created_by": "xx"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rice",
        "description": "Agrino Rice",
        "price": "3.45",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Spaghetti",
        "description": "Barilla",
        "price": "2.10",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Canned Tomatoes",
        "description": "Kyknos",
        "price": "3.40",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Bacon",
        "description": "Nikas Bacon",
        "price": "2.85",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Croissants",
        "description": "Molto",
        "price": "3.50",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Beef",
        "description": "Ground",
        "price": "12.50",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Flour",
        "description": "Traditional Flour",
        "price": "3.50",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Oregano",
        "description": "Traditional oregano",
        "price": "0.70",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "Tortellini",
        "description": "Authentic tortellini",
        "price": "4.22",
        "comments": []
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "name": "Milk",
        "description": "Delta",
        "price": "1.10",
        "comments": []
    }
]
```

I wrote then a test (using `pytest` ) to test this endpoint:

```
import pytest
import pytest_django
from django.urls import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class TestInventoryList(APITestCase):
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_get_product_list(self):
        url = reverse('product-list')
        response = self.client.get(url)
        print(response.json())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.json()), 11) # <-- TC fails here
```

but it fails since `response.json()` returns only the first **9** objects:

```
[{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Biscuits',
    'description': 'Papadopoulou Biscuits',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '2.52'
}, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Rice',
    'description': 'Agrino Rice',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '3.45'
}, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Spaghetti',
    'description': 'Barilla',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '2.10'
}, {
    'id': 4,
    'name': 'Canned Tomatoes',
    'description': 'Kyknos',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '3.40'
}, {
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Bacon',
    'description': 'Nikas Bacon',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '2.85'
}, {
    'id': 6,
    'name': 'Croissants',
    'description': 'Molto',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '3.50'
}, {
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'Beef',
    'description': 'Ground',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '12.50'
}, {
    'id': 8,
    'name': 'Flour',
    'description': 'Traditional Flour',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '3.50'
}, {
    'id': 9,
    'name': 'Oregano',
    'description': 'Traditional oregano',
    'comments': [],
    'price': '0.70'
}]
```

A couple of observations here:

1. The queryset returned in my test case does not contain the comments for my first product even-though when accessed via postman I can see the comments. `Comments` is a different `django` model which is accessed through this nested endpoint: `url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/comments/$', views.CommentsList.as_view())`
2. I inserted the last two products as well as the comment for my first product (none of which is returned in the latter queryset) using `POST` and an `API` auth token. Is this an information that I should somehow include in my test case?

---

***EDIT***

`models.py`

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)


class Comments(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='comments')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    comments = models.TextField()
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'products/$', views.InventoryList.as_view(), name='product-list'),
    url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.InventoryDetail.as_view()),
    url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/comments/$', views.CommentsList.as_view()),
    url(r'^products/(?P<product_id>[0-9]+)/comments/(?P<comment_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.CommentsDetail.as_view()),
]
```

`views.py`

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly
from .models import Product, Comments
from .serializers import ProductSerializer, CommentSerializer
from .permissions import IsAdminOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly


class InventoryList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'product_id'


class InventoryDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly, )
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'product_id'


class CommentsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, )
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'product_id'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user, product_id=self.kwargs['product_id'])

    def get_queryset(self):
        product = self.kwargs['product_id']
        return Comments.objects.filter(product__id=product)


class CommentsDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnerOrReadOnly)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'comment_id'

    def get_queryset(self):
        comment = self.kwargs['comment_id']
        return Comments.objects.filter(id=comment)
```

`permissions.py`

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS


class IsAdminOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        else:
            return request.user.is_staff


class IsOwnerOrReadOnly(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return obj.created_by == request.user
```

Comment: Things coming to mind: different database or different pagination settings used for testing.

Comment: Do you have any specific check in mind that I can do to verify both of your suggestions? As far as I remember, I haven't changed anything regarding pagination and I only use one DB in my virtual env.  Do you think the problem may has something to do with the API token?

Comment: As for the db, just check whether you have the entities in the table: add `assert Product.objects.get(pk=10).name == 'Tortellini'` to the test, does the test pass the line?

Comment: As for pagination, on second thought it's probably not an issue here as you're also missing the comments by the first product.

Comment: Entities are in the table

Comment: Why don't you use something like `setUpClass` or `setUpTestData` for testing your views? It will be more robust and independent of your production data.

Comment: @cezar While I get your point of creating mock data in order to test my views, I'm more interested in why there is such discrepancy in the test query-set.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting question. I'm also like you, no matter how important a bug for the project is, I want to solve it at any price. I strongly suspect there must be something with the issues you state in point 2. How did you create the first 9 entries?

Comment: @kingJulian So you entered the first 9 elements anonymously and then you created a security measure (aka `TokenAuthenitcation`)?

Comment: There is plenty of room for speculation. It would be better to see your `InventoryList` and an example of creation of one of the first 9 and one of the last two entries. There must be some issue with the authentication. It's important also if you have any settings regarding Django REST Framework in `settings.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect, (without having your product model at hand) that you are not getting all the elements from the products table, for the following reasons:

- You created your first 9 elements manually, without registering them to a specific user.
- Afterward, you added an authentication method (`TokenAuthentication`) and create some users with access tokens.
- Because you added an authentication method, you probably added `@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,)) / permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,)` to your `product-list` view.
  That restricts any unauthenticated user from accessing the `product-list`.
  **The unauthenticated-anonymous users will only see the anonymous elements of your database.**
- You added the next 2 elements and the comment with one of the registered users, which in turn registered those elements to the user-creator, therefore you cannot access them without an authenticated user.

To access resources that need authentication from the DRF's test client, you need to authenticate your user first.
You can use [`force_authenticate`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#forcing-authentication) method:

```
class TestInventoryList(APITestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.req_factory = APIRequestFactory()
        self.view =  views.InventoryList.as_view({'get': 'list',})

    @pytest.mark.django_db
    def test_get_product_list(self):
        url = reverse('product-list')
        request = self.client.get(url)
        force_authenticate(request, user=YOUR_USER)
        response = self.view(request)
        print(response.json())
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(len(response.json()), 11)
```

*This test assumes that you `list` method returns `Products.objects.all()`*

---

As @cezar points out, testing a view against real data is prone to fail (for example, when you add a new element, the `self.assertEqual(len(response.json()), 11)` will fail)

You should consider mocking your responses to create an isolated environment.

I tend to use a combination of [`factory_boy`](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy) and [`django-nose`](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) (`pytest` works as well).

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. First off, I edited my question to add the `model`. Secondly,  your logic is right. I wanted only `admin` users to add products so I had the `POST` method allowed only to that type of users. I then created an endpoint (see `urls.py`) that would return a `token` to a client after passing user name and password. I then created a `django` `superuser` and passed this username and password to get the `token` back. I then created the appropriate `permission` classes (see corresponding file) and did a `POST` request using my token.

Comment: With regards to your code; although it was helpful in the sense of pointing me towards the right direction (i.e. `force_authentication` function) it did not work for me. Specifically it said that there's an argument error in the `self.view` line. Apart from my code cannot find, for some reason, the user I created above. Thus the `force_authenticate(request, user=YOUR_USER)` line also fails. This is weird because I can see the user in my `auth_user` table but when I perform a `User.object.all()` query I cannot retrieve it.